# Runtime error in apply() function of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, runtime-error

I am doing a ML course on Coursera

When I run the following command

```
 sf['Country'] = sf['Country'].apply(transform_country)
```

Following is the error i get

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e97a176c3eea> in <module>()
----> 1 sf['Country'] = sf['Country'].apply(transform_country)

F:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab\data_structures\sarray.pyc in apply(self, fn, dtype, skip_undefined, seed)
   1892 
   1893         with cython_context():
-> 1894             return SArray(_proxy=self.__proxy__.transform(fn, dtype, skip_undefined, seed))
   1895 
   1896 

F:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab\cython\context.pyc in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
     47             if not self.show_cython_trace:
     48                 # To hide cython trace, we re-raise from here
---> 49                 raise exc_type(exc_value)
     50             else:
     51                 # To show the full trace, we do nothing and let exception propagate

RuntimeError: Runtime Exception. Cannot evaluate lambda. Lambda workers cannot not start.
```

What do I do now ?

Comment: Are we to assume that you are using pandas in Cython?

Comment: Show us your code of `transform_country` method.